# Why my string joiner emits previous string instead of the current one when the length of a current string is same as the length of a previous one

Tags: c++, templates

So, I have following fancy string joiner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Internal final
{
    ~Internal() = delete;
    static std::stringstream stream;
    static const std::ios_base::fmtflags defflags;
    template <typename T, typename ...P> struct Append
    {
        static void func(const void *const *p)
        {
            stream << *(T *)*p;
            Append<P...>::func(p + 1);
        }
    };
    template <typename T> struct Append<T>
    {
        static void func(const void *const *p)
        {
            stream << *(T *)*p;
        }
    };
    template <typename ...P> friend const char *Jo(const P &... p);
};

std::stringstream Internal::stream;
const std::ios_base::fmtflags Internal::defflags = stream.flags();

template <typename ...P> const char *Jo(const P &... p) // 'Join', returned pointer is valid until next call
{
    Internal::stream.clear();
    Internal::stream.flags(Internal::defflags);
    Internal::stream.str("");
    const void *const arr[sizeof...(P)] {&p...};
    Internal::Append<P...>::func(arr);
    static std::string ret = Internal::stream.str();
    return ret.c_str();
}
```

```
int main()
{
    // Test case:
    std::cout << Jo("Hello",',',' ',"world!!", 1); // Prints `Hello, world!!1`
    return 0;
}
```

As you see, `Jo(...)` concatenates all passed objects and returns pointer to resulting string. These objects can have every type that `stringstream` accepts. Also, this function accepts stream manipulators and resets internal stringsteram flags every time it's called.

It works fine, but I have a single very strange problem with it.

Consider following code:

```
std::cout << Jo('1','2');
std::cout << Jo('3','4');
```

I expect it to print `1234`, but it prints `1212`.

Same happens always when I use my function multiple times in a row, when each resulting string would have same length. In these cases, it always prints first string in a sequence.

[See it live.](http://ideone.com/VRNaA0)

**Does anyone know why it happens?**

P.S. This issue is not related to `std::cout` optimizations, I tested it without `std::cout` too.

Comment: You should probably remove the `void*` madness, that's one of the selling points of templates after all.

Comment: Also why not simply using `operator<<` with a `std::ostringstream `?

Comment: @Quentin I used it because only other solution I see is passing a bunch of references to `Append()` every time. And I thought that it can make it slightly more slow on a crappy compiler, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do you mean using a stringstream manually every time I need to concat strings? Because code that uses this function is more compact.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ... and less reliable obviously ;-)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat see the edit to my answer for a solution without "a bunch of references" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static std::string ret = Internal::stream.str();
```

... is executed only once because it's the initializer of a `static` variable. Just remove it and return an `std::string` from `Internal::stream.str()`.

Here's a version of `Jo` in case you want to take inspiration. I've kept the static `stringstream`, but made it common to all instantiations of `Jo`, but i'm not sure if it makes sense to share it at all (thread-safety issues, etc). I'll leave the flag twiddling up to you ;)

```
namespace Jo_detail {
    std::stringstream stream;
}

template <class... Args>
std::string Jo(Args &&... args) {

    Jo_detail::stream.str("");

    // Classic expander trick with dummy array
    using ex = int[];
    (void) ex { 0, (void(Jo_detail::stream << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)... };

    // str() returns a copy anyway
    return Jo_detail::stream.str();
}
```

Comment: OOOPS. And looks like I didn't noticed it because there is new instance of it for every combination of arg types!

Comment: Before your edit I thought that I know *something* about template kung-fu. :) BTW, your solution *almost* works: `.clear()` clears error state, not content.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat curse that awful pre-standard interface ! It's fixed now :p

Comment: I personally find direct use of that trick less than useful.  `template<class...Fs> void run(Fs&&...fs) { using ex=int[]; (void)ex{0, (std::forward<Fs>(fs)(), void(), 0)...}; }` helper, then `run( [&]{Jo_detail::stream << std::forward<Args>(args);}...);` inside `Jo` is cleaner.  Sadly, it [runs on fewer compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0717d230cc2914b).

Comment: @Yakk ouch. That may be one of the things where I'd prefer a macro.

Comment: @Quentin Really?  The expression `run( some_lambda... );` is pretty simple.  The strange part is that the body of your lambda is pack expanded, and gcc screws up and presumes that by the time a statement ends (or maybe a block), incomplete pack expansions are an error...

Comment: @Yakk well for a single-line pattern with one single changing subexpression, I think a little macro `EXPAND(thing << foo(args));` beats it, but it's only a matter of preference of course (provided the compiler does not choke and die on an expanded lambda).